# How to find the complexity of a program to find the length of the largest sub string?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I wrote a sample javascript program to find the length of the largest sub string of a given string and it works. I am not able to calculate its time complexity. Can someone help me?
I do understand that a program with two loops is quadratic complexity, that with three loops has cubic complexity and so on. Is this always true?
This program has two loops. Can I say that its complexity is O(n^2)?

```
function AllSubStrings()
{
    var myString = prompt("Enter the string");
    var arr = myString.split("");
    var tempArr = [];
    var maxLength = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        temp = null;

        for(var j = i; j<arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(j === i)
            {
                tempArr.push(arr[j])
                temp = arr[j];
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp + arr[j];
                if(temp.length > maxLength)
                {
                    maxLength = temp.length;
                }
                tempArr.push(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    document.write("All SubStrings are: "+tempArr+"<br/>");
    document.write("Length of the largest substring is: "+maxLength);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested loops of order n (where n is the length of string), so is O(n*n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

There are some other operations which are not important in calculating big O, e.g Split, takes O(n), but compare to O(n<sup>2</sup>) is not important, or push and pop, ... in each for loop takes O(1), but it's not important if we have multiple O(1) operations.

**For elaboration:** We know that the first loop runs `n` times, but about the second loop, it will run O(n-i) time, so total running time is:

Σ(n-i) = Σ n - Σ i = n<sup>2</sup> - n(n-1)/2 = O(n^2).

Comment: Can you elaborate please. I do understand that the first loop will run n times (where n is length) but the second loop depends on i. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

As you have two loops of order N, complexity is O(N2).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : As you have two nested loops each running in order of n, the total runtime is O(n*n).

Little more detailed one: first loop runs from 0 till n-1, second one runs from i till n-1.
so for each i inner loop runs for n+n-1+n-2+...1 = n*(n+1)/2= O(n*n)